# use variable to update document in javascript function with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I use this function , mongodb will use 'hour' and 'minute' parameters like 
a string name and will not use their value ...
Can you help me ? 
Thanks

```
db.system.js.save({
 _id: "inc_visitors_statistics",
 value : function(siteId) {

     var now = new Date();
     var hour  = now.getHours();
     var minute = now.getMinutes();

     db.visitors_daily_statistics.update({siteId : siteId},
                                         { '$inc': 
                                             {  hour: 1,
                                                minute: 1 
                                             }
                                         }, 
                                         { upsert: true }
                                       );

  } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object that holds the keys using the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**, as demonstrated in the following example:

```
db.system.js.save(
{
    "_id": "inc_visitors_statistics",
    "value": function(siteId) {

        var now = new Date(),
            hour  = now.getHours(),
            minute = now.getMinutes(),
            incObj = {};

        incObj[hour.toString()] = 1;
        incObj[minute.toString()] = 1;

        db.visitors_daily_statistics.update(
            { "siteId": siteId },
            { "$inc": incObj },
            { "upsert": true }
        );

    } 
})
```

In the mongo shell, you can then use **[`db.loadServerScripts()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.loadServerScripts/#db.loadServerScripts)** to load all the scripts saved in the **`system.js`** collection for the current database and invoke the above function directly in the shell, as in the following example:

```
db.loadServerScripts();
inc_visitors_statistics("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help!

Comment: @sav931 No worries, happy to help!